# What server is react boilerplate using "under the hood"?

Tags: react-boilerplate

When you start a server on localhost using react boilerplate and type "npm start", what server is actually being used?  Apache, nginx?

Answer (score 1):

when you start server using react boilerplate installed from npmjs.org 
it will automatically start a server from express framework which runs in port 3000.
You can check your version of express framework used from nodemodules/express/package.json file